# How to get distinct values from a Table not present in multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get a unique list of values from a table which is not present in the corresponding columns in other 2 tables( multiple tables)

Here is how my Table looks :

```
-----------         -----------         -----------
Table1              Table2              Table3
---|-------         ---|-------         ---|-------
id | Value          id | Value          id | Value
---|-------         ---|-------         ---|-------
1  | A              1  | A              1  | A
2  | B              2  | C              2  | D
3  | C              3  | D              3  | E
4  | D              4  | G              4  | F
```

Now, the unique value of Table1 is "B" ( This value is not present in Table2 and Tabl3).

Similarly unique value of Table2 is "G". Similarly unique value of Table3 is "E, F".

I am using the following query :

```
select Value from Table1 where Table1.Value NOT IN (select Value from Table2);
```

Any idea how to extend into 2 tables ( or more)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `and`:

```
select Value
from Table1
where Table1.Value not in (select Value from Table2) and
      Table1.Value not in (select Value from Table3) ;
```

I discourage the using `NOT IN` with subqueries.  It doesn't behave as you would expect with `NULL` values.  If *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`, then all rows are filtered out.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.Value
from Table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.value = t1.value) and
      not exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.value = t1.value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. Appreciate your help and suggestion. I have made the changes in my code now and is working.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use left joins here:

```
SELECT t1.Value
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Value = t2.Value
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t1.Value = t3.Value
WHERE
    t2.Value IS NULL AND t2.Value IS NULL;
```